# Magento 1.9 minicart not showing product

Tags: magento, varnish

I had currently  upload  my project to new server. On new server i installed varnish . I am adding a product to cart but it is not showing a product into cart.

Is it due to varnish ?

```
<reference name="cart_sidebar">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <access>private</access>
            <flush_events>
                <sales_quote_save_after/>
            </flush_events>
            <registry_keys>
                <current_category/>
            <registry_keys>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Yes, it is due to Varnish. Have you configured the Turpentine plugin?

Comment: yes I did . And also added some code in local.xml as shown above

Comment: is it right  Or have you another solution?

Comment: Try bypassing varnish by adding a cookie named "varnish_bypass" with a value 1 to be sure that your problem is due to Varnish.

Comment: Can You please guide me how to do that and in which file ? @ Attoui Ramzi

Comment: if I bypass cookie then it only for cart block or whole site?

Comment: What do you have for "VCL Fix" in Turpentine settings? Check if the first request to a page results in "frontend" cookie being set.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: don't use it.

Over past couple days I have done extensive experiments with Turpentine generated VCL and found that with default values and use of Nginx for SSL termination it's not only not a full page cache but also a security hole.

If your Magento is any version after 1.8, first visit of a user will result in "pipe" (completely uncached) request, which is worse than any PHP based FPC.

Moreover, with the default values and Nginx for SSL - the form keys do not change from page to page effectively disabling CSRF absent your knowledge.

Here is substantial backing of [why Turpentine is of no use anymore](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/turpentine-is-not-full-page-cache).